# Flexbox Sticky Footer Issue?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been playing around with Flexbox to try and make a sticky footer, but some reason, one of my divs is overlapping the footer? When i drag the window to a larger monitory, the footer is perfect. What am i doing wrong?

Also, i would prefer to use this method instead of other methods, such as the `table` method.

Here is my Html layout:

```
<body>
    <div class="mainContent">...</div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

Inside my `mainContent` div i have the complete top portion of my website, including the header. I just need to use that as the entire Content and then have my footer.

Here is the CSS i have:

```
body
{
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.mainContent
{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}

.footer
{
    height: 75px; 
    background: #222;
    color:#EEE;
}
```

I have even tried this: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

But i get the same issue as what i currently am encountering.

**UPDATE**

As requested in the comments, i set my main content div to `overflow: auto;` but my content was covered up by the footer. How would i fix this?

Comment: It is not a flex issue, if you set  mainContent overflow: hidden it is fixed, so the flex overlay is working fine. rearrange the maincontent content instead.

Comment: @vals ok, thanks, but that does not fix my issue. Why does the content now get pushed under the footer instead of the footer being pushed down?

Comment: Also, @vals , I can't rearrange my html? Or are you just talking about layout?

Comment: I know that making mainContent overflow hidden is not a solution. It is a clue that tells you that the problem is *inside* mainContent,and not in the flexbox between body and mainContent. You have to look inside mainContent, see why it needs more space than the space available, and fix it

Comment: @vals Yes, i know. I did some digging and found out that my content div inside mainCOntent had absolute positioning. Please post your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a few more rules into your css to get the result you seek.
As it is now, it is basically stating that when the space gets reduced, your main content should take more space. Therefore, the footer does not really gets overlapped but rather its size decreases.

Here is something I had done a few months ago... A lot of rules in the css are legacy so be careful but I believe it is close to what you aim to do :
http://plnkr.co/edit/o2BAwvg3XV4YjwAwwmYR?p=preview

But really I encourage you to use this to create your flex css rules :
http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time before if found these quick and robust solutions using CSS3 Flexbox or Grid to solve this problem. I hope this helps.

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

This should work for both for IE and Chrome:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer, header {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

You can also try Grid Layout by

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto;
}

footer {
  grid-row: 3/4;
}
```

Refer my website: http://matthiassommer.it/web/javascript/sticky-footer-css3-flexbox-grid/

Answer (score 0):

I know an answer has already been accepted, but I have here a very simple example using just the code you need (and some javascript to demonstrate).

https://codepen.io/alexmccabe/pen/RgMBjJ

Here is what is happening:

First you set the `body` and the `html` to 100% of the browser height.

```
html,
body { height: 100%; }
```

Then you set a wrapper element to have a `min-height` of 100%, and to display flex. The column makes sure the elements don't get placed next to each other.

```
.site-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

And now the footer gets `margin-top` of `auto`. This sits it at the bottom of the browser window.

```
.site-footer {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Note: Make sure that you include any old browser styles, and watch out for Safari 8. That can be a tricky one sometimes.